# Parameter is not visible in the deployed SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, analytics, msbi

[image]I need to use environment variables instead of the set parameters of the SSIS package / project.
I have the following problem:

1. I create a SSIS project/package and project/package parameters
2. deploying the project in SSISDB MS SQL Server
3. why when I configure the project, the parameters created in the SSIS project are not displayed in the properties? (I want to bind this setting with an environment variable)

[image: 2]

Comment: Everything that you show here is correct and you should be able to see the parameters configured at both the project and package level.  Could you add screen shots of the parameter configuration in the project?

Comment: Sure, I created two identical parameters at different levels: package and project level in an attempt to display the parameter 
Here pic is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOvjL.jpg

Comment: That's all correct as well.  The only thing I can suggest is to confirm that you have deployed the code to the right server and that you are connected to the right server when you are checking the configuration.

Comment: Are you configuring the project after it is deployed to the Integration Services Catalog in SQL Server?  You won't see Environment Variables in your development tool, they only exist on the server.  Also, project variables won't be seen when viewing the package and vice versa

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestive thought, my mistake was that I deployed the project via SSISDB before.
I tried to deploy the project via SSIS soft and now the parameters are displayed

Answer (score 3):

You need to deploy the project first If you deploy the only the packages it won't retrieve the parameters.